# Smarty php variables output

Tags: php, smarty

Using [realestate script 3](http://www.realestatescript.eu/) which uses [smarty 3](http://www.smarty.net/).

I managed to create the loop which gets information from the database.

```
<?php
function smarty_function_my_plugin($params,&$smarty)
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","res3");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM res3_listings WHERE listing_type_id=5 ORDER BY views DESC");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           $title=$row['title_1'];
           $price=$row['price'] ;
           $id=$row['listing_id'];
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT listing_photo_file FROM res3_listing_photos WHERE listing_photo_id=1");
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $picture=$row['listing_photo_file'];
           }
           echo $title. "<br/>".$price."<br/>".$picture;
           $smarty->assign('naslov', $title);
           echo "<br>";
       }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    echo '<h1>Test</h1>';
}
?>
```

So I put the script in plugins folder and return TEST echo at the end of script and 3 variables $title, $price, $picture. Using command in template {my_plugin}

But I want to have access to these variables so I can call them in *.tpl file, e.g.: {$title}

That way I can put HTML part in .tpl file and just insert variables I need from that function.

It should loop for 10 results on template file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically your code have assigned to the `naslov` smarty variable the last title.
You can change it to append if you would access all of them.
This way theoretically after the `{my_plugin}` call you can access the titles in the `{$naslov}` variable.

Or you can return in your template with a `$smarty->fetch('othertemplate.tpl')` And you can use these variables in `othertemplate.tpl`.

For limiting the result to at most 10, probably the easiest way to append `limit 10` to your db query.